# What does SampleRate.MS16, MS32, MS128 stand for when associated with sensor listeners?

Tags: android, sensors, microsoft-band

I am developing an application which makes use of the **Microsoft Band sensors.** For most of the sensors, whenever registering the listener, a **SampleRate** must be associated. The possible values of this **SampleRate** are:

- MS16
- MS32
- MS128

My first feeling is that they represent the time it takes for one sample to be processed, more precisely the frequency with which they are processed, but I can't find this information anywhere.

I appreciate any feedback on this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems my intuition was pretty close to the truth. I conducted some experiments and indeed the **SampleRate** refers to the frequency with which measurements are done. The unit of time is in **seconds**.

Thus, for a **SampleRate = x**, a sensor value is retrieved every **1 / x seconds**.

This is a simple experiment to prove it. For **SampleRate.MS32** the following values were shown in the logat:

[...]

06-17 11:28:34.**748**  30673-30744/com.salve E/ACCELEROMETER﹕ 0.9975586

06-17 11:28:34.**777**  30673-30744/com.salve E/ACCELEROMETER﹕ 0.99853516

06-17 11:28:34.**810**  30673-30744/com.salve E/ACCELEROMETER﹕ 0.9970703

06-17 11:28:34.**842**  30673-30744/com.salve E/ACCELEROMETER﹕ 0.9987793

06-17 11:28:34.**872**  30673-30744/com.salve E/ACCELEROMETER﹕ 0.99658203

06-17 11:28:34.**906**  30673-30744/com.salve E/ACCELEROMETER﹕ 0.9987793

[...]

When comparing the values in bold, a difference close to 32 between adjacent values is found. Maybe it is not quite 32 because of additional lag cause by the Bluetooth transmission or other intermediary processes that occur.

Comment: 1/32 is 0.03125. Are you sure you don't mean seconds? since 0.03125 is ~32ms